# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection is not working in new project

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledbconnection

The code to read the content from an Excel file does not work in my new program, see attached image.
It works without problems in another older program I made a while ago with .NET Framework 4.0.
The new program is with .NET 8.0.

Any suggestions on what I need to do to get it working?

```
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + selectedNOD + "$A1:I49]", MyConnection)
```

Visual Studio 2022
Windows Forms APP (Visual Basic)

[IMAGE: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Wg6.jpg)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code unless it genuinely adds value and, when it does, always post the code as text as well, formatted as code. If there are error messages, you need to provide them too, posted as text and formatted appropriately, i.e. probably as quotes.

Comment: Hi. I added the image just to show what the problem is as I thougt it would show my problem with the code.

Comment: As I said, you can post a screenshot if it adds value - in this case it probably does because it shows where the errors are - but you ALWAYS need to post the code as text regardless. We can't copy and paste text from a picture if we want to test your code for ourselves. The same goes for error messages, if we want to search for information on them.

Comment: Yes, and I posted the code as text as well so I don't understand...
(I updated my Q withe code just a few minutes later before your comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that you haven't installed the `System.Data.OleDb` NuGet package. In .NET Framework projects, the *System.Data.dll* assembly is generally referenced by default and that contains the `SqlClient`, `OleDb` and `Odbc` ADO.NET providers. In .NET Core projects, you have to install the NuGet package(s) for the specific provider(s) you want. This will be the case for many types in .NET Core. Note that .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core.

There are various ways that you can install NuGet packages but the simplest is probably to right-click the project, select the option to manage NuGet packages and then use the GUI provided.